# Designing e-commerce shop page and single product page - what is the correct approach?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, e-commerce

I have been working on an e-commerce site design (self-learning). The site is a clothing shop and it has many categories (like saree, stoles, dresses, etc) and many subcategories (i.e. under saree it has cotton and khadi, under cotton it has plain and stripped and so on).

Every category is supposed to have multiple products displayed as a grid (that is 'shop' page). When I click on a product, it should redirect to a single product page.

Now I cannot decide what would be the best way to start designing those pages. Should I create only a single shop page design for all the category shop pages or should I create a dedicated page for every category shop?

Same is for the single product page. Should I create one design and then fill the image, description, price from the database according to the product code, or should I have a dedicated page?

I am using HTML 5 and Bootstrap 4. I have searched google but I cannot find any relevant answer.

If this question seems silly or dumb or both, please know that I am a beginner and willing to learn more. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Dear Rimi it's better you include some work (for example: a snippet of code) to get better answer.

Answer (score 0):

E-commerce websites have standard features and capabilities. In order to find out the basics of these standards, I recommend you to view and analyze the features of open-source projects such as NopCommerce which is an open-source project based on .Net framework and enhanced by client frameworks like Bootstrap.